# Simple Functions: L1-Cauchy?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Given a measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal B(\Omega), \mu)$.

Consider simple functions:
$$s\in\mathcal{B}(\Omega,\mathbb{C}):\quad s=\sum_ka_k\chi_{A_k}$$

Suppose it is I-Cauchy:
$$\left|\int_\Omega(s_m-s_n)\mathrm{d}\mu\right|\stackrel{m,n\to\infty}\longrightarrow0$$

Does it imply L1-Cauchy:
$$\int_\Omega|s_m-s_n|\mathrm{d}\mu\stackrel{m,n\to\infty}\longrightarrow0$$

What example could serve?

Comment: I improved the formatting a bit, hope you don't mind. Also technically a measure space is a triple (underlying set, $\sigma$-algebra, measure) so I changed that part ;)

Comment: @Math1000: Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Meanwhile I got it:*

Given the real line $\mathbb{R}$.

Consider simple functions:
$$s_n:=-\chi_{(-n-1,-n]}+\chi_{(n,n+1]}$$

Then it is I-cauchy:
$$\left|\int_\mathbb{R}(s_m-s_n)\mathrm{d}\lambda\right|=0\stackrel{m,n\to\infty}{\to}0$$

But it is not L1-cauchy:
$$\int_\mathbb{R}|s_m-s_n|\mathrm{d}\lambda=4\stackrel{m,n\to\infty}{\to}0$$

*(This example can be modified.)*